# Ocultar todos os conteudos diferentes do selecionado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei um código em javascript que oculta todas as divs diferentes do valor que foi selecionado no `select`.

```
$(".filter-target").change(function() {
  var target = $(this).val();
  if (target == 0) {
      $('[data-target]').removeClass('hidden');
      return;
  }
  var self = $('[data-target="'+target+'"]');
  $('[data-target]').not(self).toggleClass('hidden');
```

});

Quando eu seleciono a opção que eu tenho exibida as outras se ocultam normalmente, porém se eu for testando as demais elas começam a ficar bagunçadas e não obedecem a ordem de "ocultar todos os que não forem x", as que eram para aparecer desaparecem e virse e versa.
o que pode estar errado?

Comment: Seria interessante ter um exemplo no Snippet.

Comment: "elas começam a ficar bagunçadas e não obedecem a ordem de "ocultar todos os que não forem x", isso não está muito revelante.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o conteudo é dinamico em um plugin que estou usando `(fullcalendar)`, fica dificil criar um snippet.

Comment: @nicematt, quando eu digo que fica bagunçado significa que os que não eram para aparecer aparecem, os que eram pra aparecer desaparecem, adicionei mais conteudo para melhorar a pergunta, obg.

Answer (score 0):

O que notei foi que:

- você esqueceu de exibir os elementos iguais à `self`;
- e que você está sempre alternando a classe `"hidden"`, o que pode pode acabar fazendo elementos que eram para ser invisíveis como "visíveis". Você poderia tentar adicionar em vez.

---

```
var $self = $('[data-target="'+target+'"]');

/* torna os elementos iguais visíveis (caso invisíveis) */
$self.removeClass('hidden');

/* torna os elementos diferentes invisíveis (caso visíveis) */
$('[data-target]').not($self).addClass('hidden');
```

---

Observação: não posso afirmar, até porque não uso jQuery, mas acho que o método `addClass` e `removeClass` já resolvem o problema de várias classes do mesmo nome em um elemento.